# JavaScript event object target field has different value than event.target

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

Why is it that the event object (e) returned to the jQuery callback contains "target" field with a value of (`{}`), but yields an URL ("http://www.myurl.com") when logged as `e.target`?

Shouldn't the "target" field contain the same value as `e.target`? How does it work? I'm confused.

```
$('.ckfilter').click(function(e){

   e.preventDefault();   

   console.log("e:",e);
   console.log("e.target:",e.target);
});

e: 
({originalEvent:({}), 
  type:"click", 
  isDefaultPrevented:function K() {return !0;}, 
  timeStamp:22619729, 
  jQuery172031920598426947033:true, 
  toElement:(void 0), 
  screenY:328, 
  screenX:674, 
  pageY:204, 
  pageX:154, 
  offsetY:(void 0), 
  offsetX:(void 0), 
  fromElement:(void 0), 
  clientY:204, 
  clientX:154, 
  buttons:1, 
  button:0, 
  which:1, 
  view:({}), 
  target:({}), 
  shiftKey:false, 
  relatedTarget:null, 
  metaKey:false, 
  eventPhase:3, 
  currentTarget:({}),
  ctrlKey:false, 
  cancelable:true, 
  bubbles:true, 
  altKey:false, 
  srcElement:(void 0), 
  relatedNode:(void 0), 
  attrName:(void 0), 
  attrChange:(void 0),  
  delegateTarget:({}), 
  data:null, 
  handleObj:{type:"click", 
             origType:"click", 
             data:null, 
             handler:(function (e) {e.preventDefault(); }),
              guid:18, 
              selector:null, 
              quick:null, 
              namespace:""}
}) 
    
e.target: "http://www.myurl.com"
```

Comment: Are you sure? Could you setup a live demo, maybe on jsfiddle?

Comment: Here's my live demo on jsfiddle-     http://jsfiddle.net/uLwgP/

Comment: Your fiddle outputs the following to me, on Chrome: `e.target: <a href=​"/​Category/​link">​Link​</a>​` (i.e., the target element, not the url)

Comment: On firefox, I got e.target: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Category/link, which is different than in Chrome but I'm ok with that. My issue is if I look at the e object itself, the target field shows up as target:({}) as opposed to target:<a href=​"/​Category/​link">​Link​</a>​ or target: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Category/link.                                                               Thank you.

Comment: I don't see that in either Chrome or Firefox... See http://i.stack.imgur.com/W7ICm.png and http://i.stack.imgur.com/mknpM.png